# Cannot access this property under async function

Tags: javascript

```js
lookforcustomers(value){
  if (value == 'on') {
    var name = 'subash';

    this.intervalid = setInterval(async function getnearplaces(nameref) {
      console.log('running', this.name)

      //  console.log('loc',outerthis.state.lastknownlocation.latitude)

      // var driverpoint = new Parse.GeoPoint({latitude:this.ref.state.lastknownlocation.latitude, longitude:this.ref.state.lastknownlocation.longitude});
      //  var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("Booking");
      // const query = new Parse.Query(PlaceObject);
      // query.equalTo("hired",false);
      // query.near("pick", driverpoint);
      // query.limit(1);
      //  const placesObjects = await query.find().then((object) => {
      //    console.log(object[0])
      //  }, (error) => {
      //
      //  console.log('error while looking for the customers')
      //  });

    }, 10000);
  }
}
```

I just need to access name-value from `getnearplacesfuntion()`. When I try to log the name value it is not printing. Is there any other procedure to access name value or is there any flaw in code above?

Comment: Did you try to call `this.intervalid()`?

Comment: One more problem, you are calling this into `getnearplaces()` function, so `this` keyword represents for that. If you want to call like this, you should bind the keyword to the function `getnearplaces.bind(this)`. Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to access the value assigned to the variable `name` defined in this line:

```
var name = 'subash';
```

You simply need to omit the use of `this` as the inner function `getnearplaces` has access to variables defined in the context it is enclosed in.

So this:

```
console.log('running', name)
```

should print the string:

```
running subash
```

For better understanding of how **closures** work in JavaScript, you might want to read this:
[MDN - Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the async function to a arrow function:

```
lookforcustomers(value){
  if (value == 'on') {
    var name = 'subash';

    this.intervalid = setInterval(async (nameref) => {
      console.log('running', this.name)

      //  console.log('loc',outerthis.state.lastknownlocation.latitude)

      // var driverpoint = new Parse.GeoPoint({latitude:this.ref.state.lastknownlocation.latitude, longitude:this.ref.state.lastknownlocation.longitude});
      //  var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("Booking");
      // const query = new Parse.Query(PlaceObject);
      // query.equalTo("hired",false);
      // query.near("pick", driverpoint);
      // query.limit(1);
      //  const placesObjects = await query.find().then((object) => {
      //    console.log(object[0])
      //  }, (error) => {
      //
      //  console.log('error while looking for the customers')
      //  });

    }, 10000);
  }
}
```

I hope this helped.